# Error when restoring PostGIS database: "type geometry does not exist"

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pg-restore

So a colleague of mine is leaving our company and he used pg_dump (indirectly, through pgAdmin III) to dump his local database. He put the .backup file on the company server, and I'm now using pg_restor (indirectly, through pgAdmin III) to restore his tables into the company database.

But I noticed that only the tables *without* a geometry were restored.

When looking closely at the logs, I noticed that the error was the following *(sorry about the French locale)*:

```
pg_restore: [programme d'archivage (db)] could not execute query: ERREUR:  le type Â« geometry Â» n'existe pas
LIGNE 3 :     geom geometry(Point,5699),
                   ^
    La commande était : CREATE TABLE cbt_poste (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    geom geometry(Point,5699),
    nom_du_pos character varying(32),
    d...
```

Basically, it states that the type Geometry does not exist. But when I create a table with a Geometry column, in whatever schema of the database, it works successfully.

So my problem is essentially:

When I create a table with a Geometry column, everything works...
But when `pg_restore` creates a table with a Geometry column, everything happens as if the PostGIS extension never had existed.

Any experience of this kind of issue?

Comment: This could be a `search_path` problem - did you use the same version of `pg_restore` as  was used for `pg_dump`? Some `search_path` bugs have been fixed a while ago that changed behavior in this area.

Answer (score 0):

I may assume, there's no PostGIS extension installed at the database, where you're trying to restore the dump. That's why spatial data types (geometry, in particular) are not getting recognized. You may try to install PostGIS and retry pg_restore.

Answer (score 0):

See if you have postgis installed writing this in psql:

```
SELECT PostGIS_full_version();
```

if not installed, you can install it following the instructions in [postgis install instructions](https://postgis.net/install/)

If you have postgis installed, you need to make sure the extension is available in your database, if it is not, you can create it with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```